# Azure - error subscription is not registered to use namespace 'microsoft.insights'

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to create an Azure MVC app using Visual Studio 2013 following this tutorial:  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/
After step 19 I can see the created app in Solution Explorer and in Server Explorer, but the following error appears in the Azure App Service Activity window

> "MissingSubscriptionRegistration: The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'microsoft.insights'."

I can also see the Web App in the Azure portal

Could anyone help please?

Comment: I am also seeing the exact same error, while trying to deploy Azure Resource Manager templates. Had any luck yet?

Comment: Works when I check the "Add Application Insights to Project" check box on the New Project dialogue - even though the tutorial instructions are to clear it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the "Add Application Insights to project" box solved my problem (though the tutorial instructions are to clear it)

Comment: That sounds odd, because app insights is just an add on (like google analytics.)  do you have a pending update for VS? Also, if you want to check out app insights, right on your project and choose the app insights in you drop down.  Cannot remember the exact text from the drop down.

Comment: It is odd, but other people have reported the same behaviour - see discussion at the end of the above tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, I resolved the problem by going to https://manage.windowsazure.com, scrolling down to Management Services, and adding a new rule to one of the services under that subscription.  After that, you may delete the rule.

I hit this error when trying to create an alert for an Azure SQL database via PowerShell.  There were no alerts created yet for any services under that subscription.  After following the above process, I was able to create more alerts under that subscription with a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1):

Open Subscription blade, select your subscription and follow this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors#noregisteredproviderfound)

Answer (score 0):

Try to walk through the steps again. Uncheck the host in Azure option when you are creating the MVC application.  Make sure you are logged into Azure by clicking on the Tools tab >> Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription.  Once you have signed in, click on the Build tab >> Publish [Your app name].  In the profile section, select Microsoft Azure Website.  Sign into your account.  Click on the new button to the right of the website drop down options.  Fill out the form.  For now, don't attach a database.  Next through to the publish, and click publish.

http://rogalademo.azurewebsites.net/

If that doesn't work, you may want to restart your computer, or reinstall the SDK.  Also, if you your work has an ADFS account, then it can cause issues because you are already logged into the account.  That of course is if you are using a subscription that is not in the ADFS account.

Finally, I would recommend you look at the cloud services web roles.  If you go into production, they can be less expensive and you can attach other roles (e.g. worker role) to the service.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the same steps from home to check if it was work ADFS causing the issue. I got the same error on the first attempt, then I retried, this time checking the "Add Application Insights to Project" option on the New Project dialogue box (though the tutorial instructions say to clear it). This time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I created an "Application Insight" service in Azure Dashboard and the error resolved itself.